# How to Make Checkbox Status checked or unchecked based database values?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two tables like below:-

```
1. document_master                    
------------------                             
document_id   |  document_name      
------------------                             
1             | BirthCertifcate                 
2             | AadharCard      


2. student_document_detail                  
------------------                             
student_document_id |  student_id  | document_id | file_name | IsActive
------------------                             
1                   |     55       | 1           | 55_b.jpg    |    1  
2                   |     55       | 2           | 55_a.jpg    |    1
3                   |     70       | 2           |             |    0
4                   |     70       | 2           | 56_b.jpg    |    1
```

I have a form like below:-
[image]

here is my function to create form:-

```
public function get_student_document_details(){
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }


    //here i want to check if document already in table or not on this basis make status checkbox checked or unchecked
    $student_document_records = $this->mdl_student_document_upload->get_student_document_list($student_id);

    //get the document master list
    $records = $this->mdl_student_document_upload->get_document_master_list();
    $document_master_list = '';
    $sr_no = 1;
    foreach($records as $row){
        $document_master_list .='<tr>
                                    <td>'.$sr_no.'</td>
                                    <td width="100"><span style="margin-top:0;" class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-xs">
                                                    Upload <input name="student_document" id="student_document" type="file">
                                                </span></td>
                                    <td width="100"><button  class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="document_name" id="document_name" value="'.$row->DocumentName.'"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="document_master_id" id="document_master_id" value="'.$row->DocumentMasterID.'"/>
                                    '.$row->DocumentName.'
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status"/></td>
                                </tr>';
        $sr_no++;
    }
    die(json_encode($document_master_list));
}
```

My questions are:-

1. if document exists in student_document_detail table then make status checkbox checked.
2. if not or IsActive field 0 then make checkbox unchecked.
3. How to generate document upload form based on these conditions.
   Any help appreciated!. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if($row->IsActive==1)
{
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="status" id="status"/></td>';
}
else
{
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status"/></td>;
}
```

Comment: Hassaan can i check this condition in foreach loop which one I have used for get document name details alongwith other input field like file to upload document because my form is generated from document_master table

Comment: @RammeharSharma yes you can.

Comment: for this I need to create another query for student_document_detail in foreach loop is it good if I have 100000 records in this table because query performed with (student_id and document_id ) these fields are unique

Comment: @RammeharSharma It is simple `if/else` condition. This does not matter how many records you want to show. But it is recommended to using `paging` instead of displaying all 100K records on one page.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<td><input type="checkbox" <?php if($row->IsActive==1) { echo "checked" } ?> name="status" id="status"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" checked="<?php if($row->IsActive == 1){<text>true</text>}else{<text>false</text>}  ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one to check weather it is active or not

```
<td><input type="checkbox" <?php echo $row->IsActive==1) ? "checked": '' ;?> name="status" id="status"/></td>
```

**note**

I have used short if else . you can know more about this if not familiar [if else short](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Answer (score -1):

Try This May it help you

```
if($row->IsActive==1) {
  <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="status" id="status"/></td>
 }
else{
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status"/></td>
}
```

Comment: You need to choose either single or double quotes and be consistent.

Comment: @Script47 XHTML requires `checked='checked'`